# How to deploy spring boot app in a subfolder to Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I have seen similar questions about node.js on stack overflow. My folder structure is pretty normal a project folder which is the git repo with a client and server folder nested inside it. I want to only deploy the server folder to Heroku *obviously*.

After hours of searching, I found answers like setting the **PROJECT_PATH** variable to `server`. I tried that didn't work. I tried setting it to `myproject/server` didn't work. I tried `Server` didn't work. I kept getting this error

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/java
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/java.tgz
       Could not find a pom.xml file! Please check that it exists and is committed to Git.
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

I found another answer to set

```
git subtree split --branch heroku --prefix server
```

but that didn't work too. How can I achieve that? Remember the pom.xml file actually is inside the server folder.